# How to make Query for that

Tags: sql-server

I have a table structure from there i have to make a query in some different way

*Table Structure*

> 1. id unique identifier
> 2. code varchar(5) Not Null
> 3. Recording_date Datetime Not Null
> 4. Max_Temp numeric(5,2) Not Null
> 5. Min_Temp numeric(5,2) Not Null

We have some data as well in this table.We have data only for 2013 year and for first 3 months.
But the main thing is that i have to return's data in such a format like

[image]

Please help me to create a query for such a logic.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is this output for? summary of all? and the months constant? (jan/feb/march only)?

Comment: Some clarifying questions: 1) Which Sql Server version? 2) Can there be more than one record per day? 3) Can there be gaps in the days (meaning some dates have no record), and if so how should that affect the % calculation?

Comment: @Nithesh yes have to show summary of all but format is just i mentioned.have to extract months from `Recording_date` column as per month number and we are supposing that we have a small entries for first 3 months.

Comment: what about the columns. No of days when max temp<=0 and all.. what is the expressions? what exactly you want ? can u provide an example with data or little explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming you have one recording per day then

```
SELECT
    DATEPART(m, Month_Start) + ' ' + DATEPART(yyyy, Month_Start)
    , Max_Temp_Days
    , CASE
        WHEN Denominator = 0 THEN 0
        ELSE (Max_Temp_Days / Denominator) * 100
      END AS Percent_Max_Temp_Days
    , Min_Temp_Days
    , CASE
        WHEN Denominator = 0 THEN 0
        ELSE (Min_Temp_Days / Denominator) * 100
      END AS Percent_Max_Temp_Days
FROM (
    SELECT 
        DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, Recording_Date), 0) Month_Start
        , Sum(CASE WHEN Max_Temp <= 0 THEN 1 END) Max_Temp_Days
        , Sum(CASE WHEN Min_Temp <= 0 THEN 1 END) Min_Temp_Days
        , COUNT(*) Denominator
    FROM TemperatureRecordings
    WHERE Recording_Date BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-03-31'
    GROUP BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, Recording_Date), 0)
) t
ORDER BY Month_Start
```

Comment: it's ok and thanks but i want to get monthname not monthnumber,instead of `DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, Recording_Date), 0) [Month_Start]` i have to use `datename(month,Recording_Date) [Month_Start]` but when i use it, it fails,so plz help in in that case as well

Comment: Take a look at [DATEPART](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) and also maybe [CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) to look at formating dates

Comment: i use `(datename(month,Recording_Date) + ', ' +datename(year,Recording_Date)) 'monthname'` in select as well as in group by clause , now i got `monthname with year` but this time i have a order by problem, but still thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This works for all month data

```
DECLARE @maxTempratureTable table(monthName varchar(20), [No. of days Max<=0] int,[Percentage Max <=0] float)
  INSERT INTO maxTempratureTable 
  SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, Recording_date, 106), 8) , 
           COUNT(*) ,
           COUNT(*) / DAY(DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,-1,Recording_date),-1)) * 100 

    FROM tablename
    WHERE Max_Temp <=0
    GROUP BY RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, Recording_date, 106), 8)

DECLARE @minTempratureTable table(monthName varchar(20), [No. of days Min<=0] int,[Percentage Min<=0] float)
  INSERT INTO @minTempratureTable 
  SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, Recording_date, 106), 8) , 
           COUNT(*) ,
           COUNT(*) / DAY(DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,-1,Recording_date),-1)) * 100 

    FROM tablename
    WHERE Min_Temp <=0
    GROUP BY RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, Recording_date, 106), 8)


SELECT * FROM @minTempratureTable min
INNER JOIN @maxTempratureTable max
ON min.monthName = max.monthName
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
      MONTH(Recording_date),
      SUM(CASE WHEN Max_Temp <= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 
      SUM(CASE WHEN Max_Temp <= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(*),
      SUM( CASE WHEN Min_Temp <= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ),
      SUM( CASE WHEN Min_Temp <= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )  / COUNT(*)
FROM temperatures
GROUP BY MONTH(Recording_date)
```

Comment: thanks dear but instead of month number i want to use monthname.